# yFiles 2 : overlaping and resizing

Tags: graph, yfiles

i try to use yFiles 2 to create a graph with multiple feature. Actually we have something witch work but we lot of behaviours overriding the yworks standard and we want better used it.

We 2 main feature witch cause problems :

- no overlaping between our nodes.
- a hierachy of node where parent element can be resized but when border intersect with child element we try (if no overlapping) to move it inside his parent.

The idea is too better integrate yworks to benefit standard feature. for example, use standard layout manager and not our one.
Today, we are overriding setSize and setLocation.

I think there is many way to do this. My ideas are :

- use override HotSpotMode (updateNodeRealizerBounds) in EditMode.
- or override the NodeLayout
  Is it the good way ? Is there a better way ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you specify the scenario in which nodes overlap one another? And can you post your code?

Comment: The node can be moved or resized by a user. When this actions are performed we want to block overlapping. between node. We can move a group of node and it's the same. And maybe if possible resize group of node too.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a feature/parameter that prevents overlapping in this scenario, but it doesn't mean that there isn't one. Did you try to contact their support? They helped me a lot in the past.